# Post javascript variable to PHP and return results inside Javascript Method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, swiper.js

I have a javascript function that runs each time a slider is changed in a slideshow checking for 2 conditions:

Is this the last slide in the slideshow and is the **activeIndex** less than the total records of the database table where all slides come from.

If so, fetch 3 more records from the database starting at the same number as the javascript **activeIndex** and append the results to the slider.

Can I do some sort of post and return results into the value of **mySwiper.appendSlide** method?

```
    ...
    keyboardControl: true,
    onSlideNextStart: function(){          
    if ((mySwiper.isEnd == true) && (mySwiper.activeIndex < <?php echo $totalCount; ?>)) {
    mySwiper.appendSlide('***return HTML here from post***');
      }         
     }
```

Comment: Do you use jQuery? If you use, then have a look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ajax:

```
keyboardControl: true,
onSlideNextStart: function(){          
  if ((mySwiper.isEnd == true) && (mySwiper.activeIndex < <?php echo $totalCount; ?>)) {
    $.post( 'php_that_return_sliders.php', { activeIndex :mySwiper.activeIndex }).done(function( data ) {
         mySwiper.appendSlide( data );
    });        
  }         
}
```

Create a *php_that_return_sliders.php* that returns sliders html based on activeIndex sent in $_POST.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much. Was also wondering how would you post more variables:  {activeIndex :mySwiper.activeIndex, var2:value } ?

Comment: Yes, right. Coma separated list of pairs key:value.